# Time in ISO format is converted to my local time not time of location using C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json

I have read all the other problems under this title but none of the answers address my problem. I am using C# application.

```
DateTime Foo = DateTime.Parse(TimeInISOFmt);
// TimeInISOFmt = HH:mm:ssT±UTCoffset
// Foo is now in my local time not the time returned.
```

Is the a better way than adding to the DateTime.Parse command .ToUniversalTime().AddSeconds(UTCoffset + DSToffset)?

Answer (score 0):

The char following the seconds should be Z, not T. Maybe that's why?

The T is for separating date and time (e.g. 2016-06-21T12:34:56Z)